# From AWS CLIi pipe output to existing file on specific line

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, awk, sed

I'm currently working on writing an Ansible Playbook and i'm looking for a command that gets AWS private IP addresses and place them in an existing file on an exact line.

I'm able to do the first part:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=ams*" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" --query "Reservations[].Instances[][PrivateIpAddress]"
```

However I'd like to pipe that to a file (inventory.ini) starting on line 2

I'm thinking I should use `sed` and `awk` but I cant figure out how to pass variables into those utilities.  I would like to do this all in one command - something like:

```
aws command | sed -i '' '2s/.*/[command output]/' inventory.ini
```

Comment: `sed` butchers line endings on WIndows. If its an INI file (as in Windows INI file), then you will need to run `unix2dos.exe` on it after running things through `sed`.

Comment: It's not a windows ini file. It's an ansible ini file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=ams*" \
    "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
    --query "Reservations[].Instances[][PrivateIpAddress]" \
     | sed -i '1r /dev/stdin' inventory.ini
```

sed commands `1r /dev/stdin` mean 'after reading line number 1 read everyting from stdin'.

Comment: is there any way to have this replace inline say if I was to run it again and wanted to replace the last ips appended to the inventory.ini file

Answer (score 0):

Put the AWS command inside of command substitution.  In the shell anything inside of `$()` will run the command and the put the output of the command in that spot.  So if your `sed` is correct you could:

```
sed -i '' "2s/.*/$(aws command)/" inventory.ini
```

Note that I switched the second set of quotes to double quotes so that interpolation will work.

## Addendum: quoting the AWS command

Because your AWS command includes double quoted sections it won't work to just put that inside of the double quoted `sed` argument.  You could replace all of the double quotes in the command with single quotes, but there could be some cases where that doesn't work.  In general it is easier to break this up into two steps:

```
AWS_OUTPUT=$(aws command)
sed -i '' "2s/.*/$AWS_OUTPUT/" inventory.ini
```

Comment: sed: 1: "2s/.*/[
     [
         " ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern

Comment: sed -i '' "2s/.*/$(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=ams*" "Name=instanc
e-state-name,Values=running" --query "Reservations[].Instances[][PrivateIpAddress]")/" tester.txt

Comment: You can't have double quotes inside of double quotes.  I'll edit my answer to explain this better.

Answer (score 0):

Try jq:
jq is a json parsing tool which you can get here: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/.

I am already doing something similar. Here is an example with PublicDnsName. Just replace that with the private ip field.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --profile us-east-1 \
   | jq -r '.Reservations[0].Instances[0].PublicDnsName' >> myPublicDNS.txt


$ cat myPublicDNS.txt
ec2-54-226-5-78.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-54-208-59-154.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: unfortunately the machine im using doesnt have jq installed.  I could install it but the playbook will run on other machines that also will not have jq.  I could install jq in the playbook but the machines are meant to be kept as is